# NoMethodError: Undefined method 'type' for nil:NilClass in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timezone

Getting a NoMethodError when trying to load up one of the pages on my website built with Rails. See the full stack trace below.

If I change `false` to `true` in production.rb at line

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

then the problem goes away, but I have to restart the Rails server every time I make a change to any file. It seems like the problem is related to checking the type of a column in my DB, but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Controller action:

```
def manage
  @view_data = {}
  if (@view_data[:product] = Product.find(params[:id])).nil?
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
  @view_data[:backlog] = Task.where("product_id = ? AND status < ?", params[:id], Task::STATUS_COMPLETED)
                          .page(params[:page]).per(10)
  @view_data[:completed] = Task.where(product_id: params[:id], status: Task::STATUS_COMPLETED)
                            .page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

There are four columns on the 'tasks' table that are type datetime--I think those are causing the problem, but I'm not fully sure.

Full stack trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass:
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:60:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:24:in `attribute_cast_code'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/serialization.rb:80:in `attribute_cast_code'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:72:in `define_method_attribute'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:29:in `define_method_attribute'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:267:in `block in define_attribute_method'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:260:in `define_attribute_method'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
  activemodel (3.2.13) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:256:in `define_attribute_methods'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:66:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:63:in `define_attribute_methods'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `respond_to?'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:398:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_initialize_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/base.rb:501:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:14:in `manage'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__115665803178931257__process_action__4080704983955383443__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4157597128006817714__call__2909158845673021585__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
```

Comment: first of all one must not use column name like `type` or `date` while creating the table. Shortest solution as I think is rename the column to `types` instead of `type`

Comment: also it would be more helpful if you provide complete error stack

Comment: Thanks for the response. None of my columns are named `type` or `date`, but it seems like Rails is checking the type of one of my columns (e.g. string, text, datetime, etc.) and it's failing. I'm at work now, but I'll provide the complete stack when I can.

Comment: Can you share complete error stacktrace when you get this error. While loading which page you get this error? Could you share the request details generated in the server log(where you are running rails server) with params hash for that page.

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet, not completely, but just enough to understand the cause?

Comment: See full stack trace and controller action above.

Comment: Please include related models and sample data .I also want to look datetime field  and also tell the database which you are using.

Comment: Could you please give the view content where you are trying to display your data?

Comment: You are running in production mode, yes? Why do you need to reload classes? Do you have this error in development mode as well?

Comment: Please refer to my answer for this same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33971877/1248725

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a model with 76 attributes, and one of them was named 'class', this was causing the error and exception.

So, I did:

- rake/bin db:rollback
- rails d scaffold MyModel
- rename 'class' column in scaffold generator command
- rename 'class' in csv header
- rails g scaffold MyModel blablaba..
- rake/bin db:migrate
- import data
- rails s

And works :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your error is related to [this bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1339-arbase-should-not-be-nuking-its-children-just-because-it-lost-interest). There are some proposed solutions that may be relevant for your situation, or you could try [this fix by alsemyonov](https://gist.github.com/alsemyonov/88826).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting config.autoload_once_paths