# Rails 4.2 Time_zone_conversion.rb Error. How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am totally lost on this one. I'm using ruby 2.2.4 and upgrading an app from rails 4.1.0 to 4.2.  The app was working fine.  I changed my Gemfile to use:

```
gem 'rails', '~>4.2'
```

Then ran my spec tests and the app blew up with this error:

```
 usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -I/path-to-my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/lib:/path-to-my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-support-3.5.0/lib /path-to-my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.0/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /path-to-my-app/coverage. 22 / 1206 LOC (1.82%) covered.

/path-to-my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:64:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?': undefined method `type' for "NUMBER(38)":String (NoMethodError)
from /path-to-my-app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in inherited'
```

When I try to load the app in a browser I get an error:

```
undefined method 'type' for "NUMBER(38)":String
```

I Google'd on this and found one post.  It was here in StackOverflow: [NoMethodError: Undefined method 'type' for nil:NilClass in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666366/nomethoderror-undefined-method-type-for-nilnilclass-in-rails), which led me to: https://gist.github.com/alsemyonov/88826/revisions

I tried the fix posted in the github app, but I still get the same error.

A mention of 'time_zone_conversion.rb' in the error and something I read made me think this was :datetime related.  I have one method in a couple of models that works on the date field "updated_at".  Not sure if this is related or not.

```
def updated_at_formatted
  self.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
end
```

I'm also using the gem 'american_date'.

Any ideas on what is causing this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
Oracle enhanced adapter version 1.6 just supports Rails 4.2 and does not support Rails 4.1 or lower version of Rails. 
When using Ruby on Rails version 4.2 then in Gemfile include

```
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.6.0'
```

A co-worker and I stepped through the stacktrace on the error.  He felt that the line:

```
undefined method 'type' for "NUMBER(38)":String
```

was somehow tied to a database issue, which for this app is Oracle.  Googling on issues on the Rails 4.2 upgrade and the above oracle gem led us to the above answer.